# Phonegap iOS getjson not working - but working in desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, json, cordova

I wrote this JSON but it doesnt execute. maybe somthing wrong with my syntax?

because it does execute on a dekstop computer, but when i run with with an iphone simulator it doesnt. :/

```
$.getJSON('http://***.com/**/***.php?uid='+uid+'&hash='+hash, function(data) {
```

thanks

Comment: also it works when simulating to an iphone. its not working only in the xcode built in simulator. wierd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your config.xml access tag. From: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/config_ref_index.md.html#The%20config.xml%20File

elements define the set of external domains the app is allowed to communicate with. The default value shown above allows it to access any server. See the Domain Whitelist Guide for details.

And this is the whitelist guide: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

Comment: Hmm, then next I'd try Safari Remote Debugging (this works in PhoneGap). Check here for an example: http://css.dzone.com/articles/overview-mobile-debugging